# Using Monotouch to Access TextField Value Across Views

Tags: .net, mono, xamarin.ios

I have a login screen where the username & password is entered. I click submit and call:

```
this.PresentModalViewController(new Screen2(), true);
```

On Screen2 how do I get the value of the username textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
var newScreen = new Screen2 (username.Text, password.Text);
this.PresentModalViewController (newScreen, true);
```